# Como contar la cantidad de archivos seleccioandos en js

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tengo un código que modifica un poco el texto por defecto de seleccionar archivo con un `<label class="file">`

El código funciona correctamente pero me interesaría que cuando seleccione múltiples archivos muestre un contador en vez del ultimo archivo seleccionado.

Este es el código:

```
<label class="custom-file-upload btn btn-success btn-block rounded-pill shadow">
      <input id="input-2" name="input2[]" type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="true" data-show-caption="true">Seleccionar archivo                                    
</label>
```

Ningún fichero seleccionado

```
<script>
        $(function () {
          $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
             let nombre_fichero = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
            
             $('.custom-file-upload').next('span').html(nombre_fichero);
          });
        });
    </script>

input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Que muestre un contador en vez del último archivo va a estar complicado. ¿Te has planteado la posibilidad de usar un componente tipo [*badge*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/badge/)? (Usando CSS, o un framewirk como Bootstrap) O tal vez alguien más tenga alguna solución con alguna librería o framework que hace exactamente lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `<input type="file" />` tiene una propiedad que es `files` que contiene datos sobre los archivos seleccionados. Puedes comprobar el `length` de dicha propiedad y mostrar el mensaje que desees.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=file]').change(function() {
        const totalFicheros = $(this).get(0).files.length;
    let mensaje = '';
    if (totalFicheros > 1) {
        mensaje = `${totalFicheros} ficheros seleccionados.`
    } else {
        mensaje = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
    }
    console.log($(this).get(0).files.length)
    $('.custom-file-upload').next('span').html(mensaje);
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="custom-file-upload btn btn-success btn-block rounded-pill shadow">
      <input id="input-2" name="input2[]" type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="true" data-show-caption="true">Seleccionar archivo                                    
</label>
<span></span>
```

[get](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

[input type file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#files)